# Convert date in PHP from number to date

Tags: php, date, datetime

How do I convert this date: `1427510741` to: `2015-03-22 09:27:02` in PHP?

I tried: `$date2 = new DateTime($date1);`

but it gives me: `0741-04-08`

And I want this: `2015-03-22 09:27:02`

Comment: look here http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types and use date(DATEFORMAT,1427510741); if 1427510741 is a unix timestamp

Answer (score 2):

You're close. To use a Unix Timestamp with DateTime to must prepend an `@` before the timestamp:

```
$date2 = new DateTime('@'.$date1);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/310371)

Comment: And what will be correct format parameter in $date1->format() for 2015-03-22 09:27:02 as output ?

Comment: What a cute little demo button!

Comment: output ? --- see the DEMO ;)